# How I could show that :$\log1=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms

I would be like somone to show me or give me a prove for this :

Why $\ln 1=0$ ?

Note that $\ln$ is logarithme népérien, the natural logarithm of a number is its logarithm to 
the base $e$.

Thanks for any replies or any comments!

Comment: What is your definition of the natural logarithm?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\log 1 = \log(1\cdot1) & = \log 1+\log 1 \\[10pt]
\text{So } \log 1 & = \phantom{{}-}\log 1 + \log 1 \\[2pt]
-\log 1 & \phantom{=}-\log 1 \\[6pt]
0 & = \log 1
\end{align}
$$

Comment: thank you for your answer , since we don't know the value of log1,then log1+log1=log1 implies 2=1 ......?

Comment: @rafik No- it implies that $2\log(1)=\log(1)$, which can only be the case if $\log(1)=0$.

Think about solving the equation $2x=x$. Does this imply that $2=1$? No, because we can't divide both sides by zero.

Comment: do you know the value of log 1 in your first step or second step ?, it's make a problem to students

Comment: @rafik : $x+x=x$ implies $1=2$ ONLY if $x\ne 0$.  From $x+x=x$ one should deduce that EITHER $1=2$ or $x=0$.  Then recall that $1\ne2$, and conclude that $x=0$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: how Mathematicians put log1=0 , before all those properties of logarithms that cited ?

Comment: @rafik: what do you mean by "before"?

Comment: @rafik : What is done first can depend on what approach one takes.

Comment: Good algebra here

Comment: $\log 1 = \log \frac{1}{1} = \log 1 - \log 1 = 0$

Answer (score 9):

I will denote the natural logarithm of $x$ by $\ln x$.

There are several definitions of the natural logarithm, so I will look at two of them.

1) $\ln(-): (0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the inverse of the exponential function $e^{-}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow (0,\infty)$, where $(0,\infty)$ denotes the set of positive real numbers.  Then because $a^0=1$ for every real number $a$, particularly $e$, it follows that $\ln (1)=0$.

2) $\ln x=\int_1^x{ \frac{dt}{t}}$.  Then Evaluating at $1$ gives $\ln 1=\int_1^1{\frac{dx}{x}}=0$.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is it a common convention to denote the positive real numbers as $\mathbb{R}_{0<}$?

Comment: @Ryan I've seen it used before, but in hindsight I probably should have used something like $(0,\infty)$.  I've seen the notation $\mathbb{R}_+$ is used, but this is also sometimes used for $[0,\infty)$ as well, so I usually go out of my way to avoid it.  I think I'll change it to $(0,\infty)$ to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that $$e^0=1,$$ we may take the natural logarithm of both sides to give $$\ln(e^0)=\ln(1) \iff 0\ln(e)=\ln(1) \iff0=\ln(1).$$

Comment: (∀ a ≠ 0) a^0 = 1 => 0ln(a) = ln(1=)

Comment: A much better way to write this proof would be to use the fact that $1^1 = 1^2$ which works for any base and does not depend on $\mathrm e$.

Comment: @user147887 I suppose that I could've written $a^0=1$ and then argued in a similar fashion to generalise the result that $\log_a(1)=0$ (for $a \in \mathbb{R^+}$).

"Better"? Yes.

"Much better"? That's pushing it.

Comment: @user147887 Also, your argument is essentially what Michael Hardy has done.

Comment: Does not work for $a = 1 \in \mathbb{R}^+$. Also, your argument is essentially what Dane Bouchie has done. Nevertheless, I feel like an argument that emphasizes the fact that the logarithm takes the identity element from multiplication to the identity element of addition is better than one that relies on the empty product.

Comment: Ok, then. It's true for $a \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{1\}$.

$\log_1(1)$ is indeterminate, so it's not as if we'd get a uniquely-defined result using of $\log_1(1)$ using any other result.

That's a matter of opinion. My justification uses only the fact that $e^0=1$ which is simple to prove.

Actually, Dane Bouchie's answer was originally wrong- it was an implication, assuming that the result was true (i.e. that $\ln(1)=0$) and showing that that leads to a correct result, which is logically unsound. He must have corrected it at the time that I submitted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The way people usually learn about logarithms, before they learn any of their other properties, is that $\log_b(a)$ means "the power to which $b$ must be raised in order to get $a$".

In particular, $\ln(1)$ or $\log_e(1)$ means "the power to which $e$ must be raised in order to get $1$."

So what power do you raise $e$ to, if you want the result to be $1$?  The answer is $0$, because $e^0=1$  (and no other power of $e$ will work).  Therefore, $\log_e(1)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$\ln x = a \Leftrightarrow x = e^a$

$\ln 1 = 0 \Leftrightarrow 1 = e^0$

And since $e^0 = 1$ is a true statement, $\ln 1 = 0$.